# php query crashes when retrieving results

Tags: php, mysql

When I execute this query the code crashes at line ' $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)    '
Can someone please help me tell what is wrong in this.

```
$query2 = " SELECT time, MAX(id) FROM i_friend WHERE (user_id=$uid AND friend_id=$fid) OR (user_id=$fid AND friend_id=$uid) ";

                    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);

                    if($result2)
                    {
                             if (mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
                                $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2) 
                                 detail["last_chat_time"] = $row2[$id];
                             } else {
                                 $detail["last_chat_time"] = "";
                             }
                    }
```

Comment: there's detail var without $ prefix, if that helps

Comment: maybe a typo? `$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2) `, missing `;` `detail["last_chat_time"] = $row2[$id];` missing `$`

Comment: Please read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php your code is obsolete.

Comment: add $ prefix on detail variable

Answer (score 0):

Correct this 2 lines

```
 $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
 $detail["last_chat_time"] = $row2[$id];
```